# Remove HTMLs and CSS styles from PDF created using itext

Tags: java, itext

We are dynamically creating PDF using itext in our application. The content of the PDF is inserted by the user in the web application using a screen where he has a Rich Text Editor.

Below are the steps specifically.

1. User goes to a add PDF content page.
2. The add page has a Rich text Editor where he can enter the PDF content.
3. Sometimes user can copy/paste the content from the existing word document and enter in the RTE.
4. Once he submits the content, PDF is created.

The RTE is used because we have some other pages where we need to show the content with BOLD, italics etc.

But, we don't want this RTE stuff in the PDF being generated.

We have used some java utility to remove the RTE stuff from the content before generating the PDF.

This works normally but when the content is copied from the word document, html and css styles applied by the document are not being removed by the java utility we are using.

How can I generate the PDF without any HTML or CSS in it?

Here is the code

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(Util.removeHTML(content), font);
```

And the removeHTML method is as below

```
public static String removeHTML(String htmlString) {
    if (htmlString == null)
        return "";
    htmlString.replace("\"", "'");
    htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");
    htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("&nbsp;", "");
    return htmlString;
}
```

And below is the additional content being shown in the PDF when I copy/paste from the word document.

```
<w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="10" SemiHidden="false
UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Title" />
<w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="11" SemiHidden="false"
UnhideWhenUsed="false" QFormat="true" Name="Subtitle" />
<w:LsdException Locked="false" Priority="22" SemiHidden="false"
```

Please help !

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our application is similar, we have a Rich Text Editor (TinyMCE), and our output is PDF generated via iText PDF.   We want to have the HTML as clean as possible, and ideally only using the HTML tags supported by iText's HTMLWorker.  TinyMCE can do some of this, but there are still situations where an end user can submit HTML which is really screwed up, and which can possibly break iText's ability to generate a PDF.

We're using a combination of jSoup and jTidy + CSSParser to filter out unwanted CSS styles entered in HTML "style" attributes.   HTML entered into TinyMCE is scrubbed using this service which cleans up any paste from word markup (if the user didn't use the Paste From Word button in TinyMCE) and gives us HTML that translates well for iTextPDFs HTMLWorker.

I also found issues with table widths in iText's HTMLWorker parser (5.0.6) if the table width is in the style attribute, HTMLWorker ignores it and sets the table width to 0, so this is some logic to fix that below.  We use the following libs: a

```
com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.0.6                 // used to generate PDFs
org.jsoup:jsoup:1.5.2                       // used for cleaning HTML, primary cleaner
net.sf.jtidy:jtidy:r938                     // used for cleaning HTML, secondary cleaner
net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:0.9.5   // used to parse out unwanted HTML "style" attribute values
```

Below is some code from a Groovy service we built to scrub the HTML and only keep the tags and style attributes supported by iText + fixes the table issue.  There are a few assumptions made in the code which is specific to our application.  This is working really well for us at the moment.

```
import com.steadystate.css.parser.CSSOMParser
import org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties
import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import org.htmlcleaner.PrettyHtmlSerializer
import org.htmlcleaner.SimpleHtmlSerializer
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.safety.Cleaner
import org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist
import org.jsoup.select.Elements
import org.w3c.css.sac.InputSource
import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSRule
import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSRuleList
import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleDeclaration
import org.w3c.dom.css.CSSStyleSheet
import org.w3c.tidy.Tidy

class HtmlCleanerService {

    static transactional = true

    def cleanHTML(def html) {

        // clean with JSoup which should filter out most unwanted things and
        // ensure good html syntax
        html = soupClean(html);

        // run through JTidy to remove repeated nested tags, clean anything JSoup left out
        html = tidyClean(html);

        return html;
    }

    def tidyClean(def html) {
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy() 
        tidy.setAsciiChars(true)
        tidy.setDropEmptyParas(true)
        tidy.setDropProprietaryAttributes(true)
        tidy.setPrintBodyOnly(true)

        tidy.setEncloseText(true)
        tidy.setJoinStyles(true)
        tidy.setLogicalEmphasis(true)
        tidy.setQuoteMarks(true)
        tidy.setHideComments(true)
        tidy.setWraplen(120)

        // (makeClean || dropFontTags) = replaces presentational markup by style rules
        tidy.setMakeClean(true)     // remove presentational clutter.
        tidy.setDropFontTags(true)  

        // word2000 = drop style & class attributes and empty p, span elements
        // draconian cleaning for Word2000
        tidy.setWord2000(true)      
        tidy.setMakeBare(true)      // remove Microsoft cruft.
        tidy.setRepeatedAttributes(org.w3c.tidy.Configuration.KEEP_FIRST) // keep first or last duplicate attribute

        // TODO ? tidy.setForceOutput(true)

        def reader = new StringReader(html);
        def writer = new StringWriter();

        // hide output from stderr
        tidy.setShowWarnings(false)
        tidy.setErrout(new PrintWriter(new StringWriter()))

        tidy.parse(reader, writer); // run tidy, providing an input and output stream
        return writer.toString()
    }

    def soupClean(def html) {

        // clean the html
        Document dirty = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(html);
        Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner(createWhitelist());
        Document clean = cleaner.clean(dirty);

        // now hunt down all style attributes and ensure we only have those that render with iTextPDF
        Elements styledNodes = clean.select("[style]"); // a with href
        styledNodes.each { element ->
            def style = element.attr("style");
            def tag = element.tagName().toLowerCase()
            def newstyle = ""
            CSSOMParser parser = new CSSOMParser();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(style))
            CSSStyleDeclaration styledeclaration = parser.parseStyleDeclaration(is)
            boolean hasProps = false
            for (int i=0; i < styledeclaration.getLength(); i++) {
                def propname = styledeclaration.item(i)
                def propval = styledeclaration.getPropertyValue(propname)
                propval = propval ? propval.trim() : ""

                if (["padding-left", "text-decoration", "text-align", "font-weight", "font-style"].contains(propname)) {
                    newstyle = newstyle + propname + ": " + propval + ";"
                    hasProps = true
                }

                // standardize table widths, itextPDF won't render tables if there is only width in the
                // style attribute.  Here we ensure the width is in its own attribute, and change the value so
                // it is in percentage and no larger than 100% to avoid end users from creating really goofy
                // tables that they can't edit properly becuase they have made the width too large.
                //
                // width of the display area in the editor is about 740px, so let's ensure everything
                // is relative to that
                //
                // TODO could get into trouble with nested tables and widths within as we assume
                // one table (e.g. could have nested tables both with widths of 500)
                if (tag.equals("table") && propname.equals("width")) {
                    if (propval.endsWith("%")) {
                        // ensure it is <= 100%
                        propval = propval.replaceAll(~"[^0-9]", "")
                        propval = Math.min(100, propval.toInteger())
                    }
                    else {
                        // else we have measurement in px or assumed px, clean up and
                        // get integer value, then calculate a percentage
                        propval = propval.replaceAll(~"[^0-9]", "")
                        propval = Math.min(100, (int) (propval.toInteger() / 740)*100)
                    } 
                    element.attr("width", propval + "%")
                }
            }
            if (hasProps) {
                element.attr("style", newstyle)
            } else {
                element.removeAttr("style")
            }

        }

        return clean.body().html();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a JSoup whitelist suitable for sane HTML output and iTextPDF 
     */
    def createWhitelist() {
        Whitelist wl = new Whitelist();

        // iText supported tags
        wl.addTags(
            "br", "div", "p", "pre", "span", "blockquote", "q", "hr",
            "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6",
            "u", "strike", "s", "strong", "sub", "sup", "em", "i", "b", 
            "ul", "ol", "li", "ol",
            "table", "tbody", "td", "tfoot", "th", "thead", "tr", 
            );

        // iText attributes recognized which we care about
        // padding-left (div/p/span indentation)
        // text-align (for table right/left align)
        // text-decoration (for span/div/p underline, strikethrough)
        // font-weight (for span/div/p bolder etc)
        // font-style (for span/div/p italic etc)
        // width (for tables)
        // colspan/rowspan (for tables)

        ["span", "div", "p", "table", "ul", "ol", "pre", "td", "th"].each { tag ->
            ["style", "padding-left", "text-decoration", "text-align", "font-weight", "font-style"].each { attr ->
                wl.addAttributes(tag, attr)
            }
        }

        ["td", "th"].each { tag ->
            ["colspan", "rowspan", "width"].each { attr ->
                wl.addAttributes(tag, attr)
            }
        }
        wl.addAttributes("table", "width", "style", "cellpadding")

        // img support
        // wl.addAttributes("img", "align", "alt", "height", "src", "title", "width")


        return wl
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the text content of the HTML document, then use an XML API such as SAX or DOM to emit only the text nodes from the document. This is trivial with the DocumentTraversal API if you know your way around DOM. If I had my IDE running, I'd paste a sample ...

In addition, the removeHtml method shown is inefficient. Use Pattern.compile and cache that in a static variable and use the Matcher API to do the replacements into a StringBuffer (or perhaps StringBuilder, if that's what it uses). That way you're not creating a bunch of intermediate strings and throwing them away.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. I am not fetching the text content from the HTML document but from the database. When user submits the content from the RTE, it goes in the database first and then it is retrieved from the database and used for the PDF generation.